# How to prevent the gio open command from outputting texting in the console?

Tags: bash, bashrc, stdout

I use the `gio open` command very often, so what I have done is I added an alias for it in the .bashrc file

```
alias open="gio open"
```

Hence, I can simply write `open .` or `open ~/Pictures/example.png` as an example.

However, I can't prevent the annoying output of `gio` because it doesn't have a `--quite` option by default,
`gio open` outputs some messages during its job, for example:

```
msi@msi:~/Pictures$ open image-3.jpg 
msi@msi:~/Pictures$ 
(gthumb:37944): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:00:54.815: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
```

So what I have found is that some people were using the redirect operator to redirect the output of a command from the standard output (the shell) to `/dev/null` since everything gets written to this 'device' gets deleted automatically directly.

Could you help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suppressing error output**

Warning messages of applications, in your example "gthumb", are not send to standard output, but to `stderr`. You can suppress these messages like:

```
gio open image-3.jpg 2>/dev/null
```

An alias as

```
alias open='gio open 2>/dev/null'
```

will work to automate also that aspect in your alias.

**Supressing all output**

To eliminate all output, redirect both file descriptor 1 (`stdout`) and 2 (`stderr`) to `/dev/null`:

```
gio open image-3.jpg 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Following has the same effect, but allows you to specify the final target only once:

```
gio open image-3.jpg >/dev/null 2>&1
```

`stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null`, and `stderr` to `stdout`, which became `/dev/null`. `1` can be omitted because it is the default output.

Bash and other shells also allow this shortcut notation:

```
gio open image-3.jpg &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the number 2 indicate? errors? are there other numbers?

Comment: 2> means stderr

Comment: how to prevent stderr and stdout at the same time?

Comment: I added full detail

Comment: Thanks @vanadium